# Get a specific text with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

It's an easy enough thing, but I can't do it ... I'm trying to discard the data from Reuters. The main problem is that using beautifulsoup, I get all the html tags of the line:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.reuters.com/markets/stocks/europe'

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='__next')

stock_elems = results.find_all('tr', class_='data')

index_elem = stock_elems[0].find('a', class_='TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black-to-orange___23uc0 TextLabel__medium___t9PWg MarketsTable-name-1U4vs')
print(index_elem)
```

I'd like to get something like:

```
FTSE 100
```

But I only got all tag line:

```
<a class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black-to-orange___23uc0 TextLabel__medium___t9PWg MarketsTable-name-1U4vs" href="/quote/.FTSE">FTSE 100 Index</a>"
```

I tryied also with other texts in the page and I get the same result:

```
index_elem = stock_elems[0].find('div', class_='TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__gray___1V4fk TextLabel__regular___2X0ym MarketsTable-subcell-l_NnB')
```

> 

```
<div class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__gray___1V4fk TextLabel__regular___2X0ym MarketsTable-subcell-l_NnB">.FTSE</div>
```

Thanks for helping and time

Comment: Try calling `.text` on your element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add .text to get the text values of the tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.reuters.com/markets/stocks/europe'

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='__next')

stock_elems = results.find_all('tr', class_='data')

index_elem = stock_elems[0].find('a', class_='TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black-to-orange___23uc0 TextLabel__medium___t9PWg MarketsTable-name-1U4vs')
print(index_elem.text)
```

**Output**

```
FTSE 100 Index
```